# mongoose findOneAndUpdate works but gives an error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, findoneandupdate

I learn mongoose on NodeJS and I wanted to use usefindOneAndUpdate, it works on db I have the updates but the response gives an error and I couldn't find why help me pls.
code:

```
await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
            $set: {
                nickName: req.body.nickName,
            },
        },
        { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true },
        (err, docs) => {
            if (!err) return res.send(docs);
            else return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        }
    );
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
}
```

error:

```
"originalStack": "Error\n    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate]

(C:\\Users\\alike\\Documents\\projetsJS\\chatApp-Node-React\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\query\\wrapThunk.js:25:28)
at C:\\Users\\alike\\Documents\\projetsJS\\chatApp-Node-React\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:279:20
at _next (C:\\Users\\alike\\Documents\\projetsJS\\chatApp-Node-React\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:103:16)
at C:\\Users\\alike\\Documents\\projetsJS\\chatApp-Node-React\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:508:38
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)"
```

Edit: @GulshanAggarwal here is all the file https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4LCj.png

Comment: please share more part of your code then only it will possible for me to answer you clearly?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal I couldn't post the image in comment so posted an answer

Comment: @Kenyunki you can edit your post to share more part of your code.

Comment: Can you try to remove await once?

Comment: @TusharShahi it was that thank you lol I've always thought I needed an async/await on something like this but it works lol

Comment: No, you are already using the callback as the last param of findOneAndUpdate see.